# How to run Hadoop in Local (Standalone) Mode without ConnectionRefused Exception?

Tags: java, hadoop, connection

Following the "Hadoop: Setting up a Single-Node Cluster" tutorial (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_Single_Node), I am trying to run Hadoop in Local (Standalone) Mode but I am getting a ConnectionRefused Exception. When I try to run this command:

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

I get the following message:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From 4295i/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

A long stack trace follows this, as well as a link to http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused. **How should I avoid this exception?**

---

Alternatively, **how can I do the following 3 steps?** (they are instruction options from the link above)

1. Check the hostname the client using is correct.
2. Check the IP address the client is trying to talk to for the hostname is correct.
3. Make sure the destination address in the exception isn't 0.0.0.0 - this means that you haven't actually configured the client with the real address for that.

---

Here is my configuration in core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>    
  <property>    
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>    
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>    
  </property>    
</configuration>
```

Here is my configuration in hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>    
    <value>/home/USERNAME/pseudo/dfs/name</value>    
  </property>    
  <property>    
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>    
    <value>/home/USERNAME/pseudo/dfs/data</value>    
  </property>    
  <property>    
    <name>dfs.replication</name>    
    <value>1</value>    
  </property>    
</configuration>
```

My configurations for mapred-site.xml.template and yarn-site.xml are empty.

Comment: Namenode is not running.

Comment: @Amal G Jose How should I get it running?

Comment: cd $HADOOP_HOME/bin,  sh stop-all.sh, sh start-all.sh

Comment: @AmalGJose I found start-all.sh in $HADOOP_HOME/sbin and ran ./start-all.sh. Then I ran the command from my question again and got the same exception.

Comment: @Amal G Jose are you there still?

Comment: Can you share the configurations. core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml

Comment: @AmalGJose I updated my question with configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed some problems with the configurations. The path you mentioned for storing namenode and datanode data are not absolute. It should start with slash (/). I made the changes are the updated configs are given below. 
Another suggestion is better to keep this directories outside user home directory.

```
<configuration>

<property>

<name>dfs.name.dir</name>

<value>/home/USERNAME/pseudo/dfs/name</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>dfs.data.dir</name>

<value>/home/USERNAME/pseudo/dfs/data</value>

</property>
```

Comment: I updated my configs in hdfs-site.xml to have a "/" in front of home. Something is wrong because when I run start-all.sh and then run jps to see the running processes, namenode is not started. Only NodeManager, DataNode, SecondaryNameNode, and ResourceManager are started.

Comment: Check the directory permissions of dfs.name.dir. Perform a namenode format before starting.

Comment: What directory should I look in to find dfs.name.dir?

Comment: Follow these steps. Use the configurations mentioned in this doc. Clear all the conf in hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml. https://gist.github.com/amalgjose/e34b69e6c64120a280b8

Comment: I can't execute the first line `sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp` because I'm not in the sudoers file.

Comment: If you are not in sudoers file, login as root user. For easiness I gave 777 permission in the first step. The namenode and datanode directories will be created under the /app/hadoop/tmp directory. The subdirectories will be created automatically on namenode format and will be owned by hdfs user. If you are adding multiple users, giving restricted permission to the hadoop.tmp.dir will create issues. That is the reason for giving 777 permissions.

Comment: I cannot create the /app directory because my username not in the sudoers file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84725/discussion-between-amal-g-jose-and-ast).